# Dynamic auto scaling AWS based on messages in SQS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, autoscaling

Use case:

Every day morning the SQS will be populated (only one time, and the number of messages can vary drastically), I want to spawn new instances as per the number of messages in the queue.

eg: For 200000 messages 4 Instances, 400000 8 instances.

Is there a way by which we can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can set up a cron-job on your server or a time-triggered Lambda to query SQS to find out the number of visible messages in the queue. If you're using the AWS CLI you would run `aws sqs get-queue-attributes` and read the `ApproximateNumberOfMessages` response field to get the number of items in the queue. You would then use that number to calculate the number of instances and either call `aws ec2 run-instances --count 4` plus the rest of the parameters. Once everything is done you would terminate the instances.
2. Another way to do this would be to utilize auto-scaling and alarms. You can set up an ScaleOut policy that adds 1 server to your AutoScaling Group and trigger that policy with a CloudWatch alarm on SQS ApproximateNumberOfMessages >= some threshold. This option wouldn't wait for morning to process the queues, you'd have it running all the time. You could also have a ScaleIn policy to reduce the Desired Capacity (# of servers) in your AutoScaling Group when ApproximateNumberOfMessages <= some threshold.

Comment: Thanks Max, will try and get back to you. In the second approach the scaling in will only kicks in 1 time right? How does it spawn as many instances needed for the number of messages?

Comment: In your scaling policy set a cool down, eg. 10 minutes. As long as your alarm is triggered (>= x messages) it'll keep trying to trigger the scale up policy, but the cool down will make sure it only makes at most of server every 10 minutes. If within those 10 minutes the queue gets emptied, your alarm will transition to OK state and stop calling the scale out policy

Comment: Ok, Thanks, will go with the 1st approach as we got more control to the system in that.